# C++ Meyers Singleton as class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton

I have data that will be consumed by multiple workers in parallel. So I try construct data as Meyers Singleton, like this

```
class Data {
public:
  static Data &GetInstance() {
    static Data data();
    return data;
  }
private:
  Data() {cout << "Create data" << endl;}
  ~Data() {cout << "Destroy data" << endl;}
  Data & operator=(const Data &other);
}
```

Then I define worker class

```
class Worker {
public:
  Worker() : data_(Data::GetInstance()) {}
  work() {cout << "working on data " << data_ << endl;}
private:
  Data &data_;
}
```

Now I test it in a loop and it works

```
void do_work() {
  Worker *worker = new Worker();
  worker->work();
  delete worker;
}

for (i = 0: i < 3; i++) {
  do_work();
}
```

Output is

```
Create data
working on data 0x7febff47b700
working on data 0x7febff47b700
working on data 0x7febff47b700
Destroy data
```

But when I using threads like this

```
void* do_work() {
  Worker *worker = new Worker();
  worker->work();
  delete worker;
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

pthread_t t[3] = {0};
for (i = 0: i < 3; i++) {
  pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, do_work, (void *)NULL);
  pthread_detach(t[i]);
}
```

It crashes

```
Create data
working on data 0x7febff47b700
Destroy data
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: [Tangent] Is there a reason you are using `pthread`s instead of `std::thread`s?  If it is because you don't have C++11, do note that for a Meyers singleton to work, it needs at least C++11.

Comment: I am mildly suspicious of the fact that you `detach` each of those threads. What does the main thread do after creating and detaching them? What would happen instead if you removed the `pthread_detach()` calls, and you wrote a second loop to `join()` all of the threads after they all were created?

Comment: Addendum to Nathan Oliver's comment above to add a bit of context: The initialization of a `static` is not thread safe before C++11, so `static Data data();` could easily fail. Side note: I see destructor and copy assignment operator, but no copy constructor. Probably doesn't matter in the example, but in a more complex system [this is probably a bug-in-waiting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). In this case you want to make the copy constructor private the same as the assignment operator.

Comment: @user4581301 It's a singleton.  It shouldn't have a copy constructor.  The private assignment operator does that.

Comment: I don't use `pthread`s  but I suspect it's the `void*` return type of the function that is the problem.  Most likely it needs to just be `void*` since you aren't returning anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point. I had a note in there about deleting the copy constructor, then pulled it out because of the pre C++11 concerns and didn't replace it with anything useful.

Comment: @NathanOliver it's just for testing. I have C++11 and compiled with -std=c++11.

Comment: Your code cannot compile (except if you use the `-fpermissive` flag, which you should never do). `pthread_create` expects an argument of type `void*(*)(void*)` as thread function, but `do_work` does not have that type. If you are compiling for C++11, then just use `std::thread` instead of pthreads. That is more portable and provides a C++, rather than a C, interface.

Comment: In the C++ case rather than making the assignment operator and copy constructor `private` and unimplemented, make then `public` and delete them (`Data & operator=(const Data &other) = delete;`). If someone does copy or assign, they get a much easier to understand error message.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I tried a second loop to join and it works! thank you guys.

Comment: @xna, OK. That wasn't an answer to your question, but now I can _guess_ what happened: I'm guessing that your `main(...)` routine returned, and the runtime library destroyed the singleton (as it would normally do for any `static` variables in your program) while the detached "worker" threads still were running.